# Call SOAP service with HTTP headers Spring Java using Service Stub

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to call a SOAP service which uses Basic authentication from Spring java. 
I have the Service Stub and I am aware of the operation I need to call.

```
String finalRequestString="Entire Request string";

MYServiceStub mySVCStub= new MYServiceStub();

MYSVCSubmitInformationDocument objSubmitInformationDoc= 
MYSVCSubmitInformationDocument.Factory.newInstance();
MySVCSubmitInformation objSubmitInfo = objSubmitInformationDoc.addSubmitInformation(); //service specific methods
objSubmitInfo.setXml(finalRequestString); //Request String

ServiceClient client = mySVCStub._getServiceClient();
Options options = mySVCStub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = new HashMap<>();
requestHeaders.put("Authorization","Basic encodedUserNamePassword as it appears in SOAP UI request");
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, requestHeaders);

response= mySVCStub.submitInformation(objSubmitInformationDoc);
```

But I get error that org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The given SOAPAction http://MYVC.../mySVCsubmitInformation does not match an operation.

Any help would be appreciated.
             Thank you